# ZipFile producing empty files on 'append' mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zipfile

I'm getting inconsistent behaviors when a ZipFile is created from a file with 'a'ppend or 'w'rite mode:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

with ZipFile(open('tempdir/a.zip', 'ab+'), 'a') as z:
    z.writestr('file.txt', 'z'*100)
# file.txt is empty inside a.zip.

with ZipFile(open('tempdir/w.zip', 'wb+'), 'a') as z:
    z.writestr('file.txt', 'z'*100)
# file.txt has correct contents inside w.zip.
```

Shouldn't 'append' and 'write' modes be equivalent in this case? The files don't exist beforehand, and I expected 'a.zip' to contain a non-empty 'file.txt'.

This happens on Windows 10, Python 3.6, 64 bit.

Edit: couldn't reproduce this issue on [Windows 10, Python 3.3.5, 32 bit] or [Windows 10 Bash, Python 3.4.3, 64 bit].

Comment: This sounds more like a bug report than an actual problem. Just don't open the file in append mode? Or are you trying to append to an existing zip file?

Comment: I want to be able to read zipped files and append new ones, but still create the container it if it's missing. 'w' mode would truncate the file and lose the existing data. And I'm not sure if it's a bug or a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: If you delegate opening the file to the `ZipFile` constructor, it seems to work. I don't get an *empty* file, I get a seemingly-corrupted file, by the way.

Comment: 7zip was able to show the file list, but you are right, the zip is corrupted. And unfortunately I need to handle file-like objects, so delegating to `ZipFile` is not an option. I'm preparing to open a new issue in the Python bugtracker.