# Create a ZIP with python ZipFile

Tags: python-3.x, python-zipfile

I am simply trying to create a zip of several files with python using ZipFile, but it is constantly producing an empty .zip file.

My version of python is 3.10.8

```
from zipfile import ZipFile


files_to_zip = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt', 'file_3.txt']

with ZipFile('file_name.zip', 'w') as zip_file:
    for f in range(len(files_to_zip)):
        zip_file.write(files_to_zip[f])
```

[image: This is what I am obtaining!]

I have also tried to use append instead of write, but I get the same result. It is such a simple script that I dont know what could be the issue, maybe a bug as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43701449/zipfile-producing-empty-files-on-append-mode)?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Works fine for me on Windows. Maybe this is a unique Mac issue? Also, I assume file_3.txt was a typo in your example, and not in your actual code, as that would have thrown an error.

Comment: It seems so. I have just tried in windows and in a linux machine and the same script does work. Thank you for your answer!  

And yes, file_3.txt was a typo in the question!